# Issue when installing the last version of appcelerator studio

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

From this [post](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS#example) on appcelerator blog, titanium studio is compatible only from version 6 of node and lower, actually the studio automatically install the last version of node which is the v7 and the CLI + Liveview is not compatible with this version.

I always get this error with live view  :

```
File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable @ 127.0.0.1:8324
```

Could someone confirm me the best node version for titanium studio? 
Thank you.

Comment: Why -1 for this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator Studio 4.8.0/SDK 6.0/CLI 6.0 requires Node 4.2 and higher. However, Studio installs 4.6.0 as the default node version.

To avoid issues, it's better to have a node version between 4.2 to 4.6.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i uninstall completely the studio, node, then I install nvm with node 4.6. 
When re-installing the studio it always re-install node and the cli (which is not working also), I always get the error of liveview.
I am on a new Mac Sierra 10.12

Comment: Make sure port 8324 is free. Find more liveview trouble shooting details here -https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/LiveView#LiveView-Troubleshooting